# Can't execute a procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle

this is the procedure name :

```
procedure misowner.proc_kr_text_niki(valdate in varchar2 default '20040101'
, v_table varchar2 default 'KR_TEMP')
```

and i what to `EXEC` it. What kind of variables i have to put?

Comment: Does `exec misowner.proc_kr_text_niki('foo', 'bar');` in SQL*Plus return some error?

Comment: I want to exec from pl/sql developer. For example a have another procedure: PROCEDURE AFFLUENT_E_MAIL (p_date DATE) when i want to run i just write: exec AFFLUENT_E_MAIL (to_date ('20121228','yyyymmdd'))

Comment: So how about: exec misowner.proc_kr_text_niki('20040101', 'KR_TEMP') or replace these values with others? Do you get an error by doing this?

Comment: Yes i get an error: PLS-00201: identifier 'MISOWNER.PROC_KR_TEXT_NIKI' must be declared

Comment: I'm such an idiot i forgot to declared.....OMG. DaveRlz thx man you help me alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have default values for the parameters you should be able to surround it with a block like this, and execute it as a script if you are using a GUI tool like SQL developer or Toad

```
DECLARE
valdate VARCHAR2(10);
v_table VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN

misowner.proc_kr_text_niki;

END;
```

This works for testing, then, as suggested by BazzPsychoNut, initialize the variables, pass them in and test some more.

Answer (score 0):

You call it by providing two parameters. The first parameter (= variable) "valdate" is in varchar2. It is apparently a date inputted as text in the form YYYYMMDD. The second parameter "v_table" is a varchar2, probably the name of the table to query on.